# If cryptsetup-bin is missing does it means that file inside device is not encrypted?

Tags: cryptsetup

Please help me with the working of cryptsetup and how does the missing of cryptsetup-bin affect cryptsetup

Comment: Which distro and version of Linux are you using or trying to install?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

cryptsetup-bin is a dependency of cryptsetup, but cryptsetup-bin does not require cryptsetup to function.

From the results of `apt show cryptsetup-bin` :

```
Description: disk encryption support - command line tools
 Cryptsetup provides an interface for configuring encryption on block
 devices (such as /home or swap partitions), using the Linux kernel
 device mapper target dm-crypt. It features integrated Linux Unified Key
 Setup (LUKS) support.
```

From the results of `apt show cryptsetup` :

```
Description: disk encryption support - startup scripts
 Cryptsetup provides an interface for configuring encryption on block
 devices (such as /home or swap partitions), using the Linux kernel
 device mapper target dm-crypt. It features integrated Linux Unified Key
 Setup (LUKS) support.
```

To install cryptsetup-bin in all currently supported versions of Ubuntu open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install cryptsetup-bin
```